# IDL vector issue, appending values over ~ 30000

Tags: arrays, idl-programming-language

unfortunately I couldn't find an answer to this issue, and have had to result to asking a question. If there is an answer elsewhere, I apologise, I am new to IDL, and didn't know how to phrase this perfectly.

My code is below:

```
for i=0,delta-1 do begin
    print, flrarray[i]
    numbr_for_arr=where(del gt ((flrarray[i])-0.000001) and del lt ((flrarray[i])+0.000001))
    print,numbr_for_arr
    postnflrarray[i]=numbr_for_arr
endfor
```

delta is just a number. finalflrarray is just an array that has specific points that I need from del (a huge array)

my output is below:

```
   ...
   24.000231 ; flrarray
   23392 ; numbr_for_arr
   24.748374
   26612
   24.213783
   27473
   24.368324
   30637
   24.711283
   32432
   24.426823
   37675
   24.039426
   40733
```

Printing the flrarray, and postnflrarray

```
   ...       24.000231       24.748374       24.213783       24.368324       24.711283       24.426823       24.039426
   ...       23392           26612           27473           30637           32432           -27861          -24803
```

As you can see, somehow between printing numbr_for_array, and appending it

37675 -> -27861
and
40733 -> -24803

Any insight into why this is happening would be greatly appreciated.

I must emphasize that the flrarray array/vector is coming from an external source, so I am using this method to find where it is in my 'del' array.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

postnflrarray needs to be a 'lonarr'

ie postnflrarray=lonarr(N)
Where N is a length of the array. This comes down to the values in the array being 16-bit signed integers (max size around 32767). When you append a value larger than it, it overflows becoming negative.

Answer (score 0):

From what you have given, it looks like you are using `WHERE` on a scalar. You want to use `WHERE` with an array argument. The result will then give the indices which match the given condition. For example, to find the elements of a sine curve greater than `0.99`, do:

```
IDL> x = findgen(360) * !dtor
IDL> y = sin(x)
IDL> ind = where(y gt 0.99, count)
IDL> print, count
          17
IDL> print, ind
          82          83          84          85          86          87          88          89
          90          91          92          93          94          95          96          97
          98
IDL> print, y[ind]
     0.990268     0.992546     0.994522     0.996195     0.997564     0.998630     0.999391
     0.999848      1.00000     0.999848     0.999391     0.998630     0.997564     0.996195
     0.994522     0.992546     0.990268
```

Comment: I think Paul was using `WHERE` on his variable `del` which he said was a huge array.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a slightly altered version of your code with comments:

```
;;  If FLRARRAY is a one-dimensional array, then you could define the
;;    following outside of the for loop
;;  updn = [[flrarray - 1e-6],[flrarray + 1e-6]]
;for i=0,delta-1 do begin
for i=0L,delta-1L do begin
  print, flrarray[i]
;  numbr_for_arr=where(del gt ((flrarray[i])-0.000001) and del lt ((flrarray[i])+0.000001))
  ;;  Note:  WHERE.PRO should be returning long integers, not integers.  However, your
  ;;         output seems to suggest otherwise which is odd.
  numbr_for_arr = where(del gt (flrarray[i] - 0.000001) and del lt (flrarray[i] + 0.000001),nmb)*1L
;;  numbr_for_arr = where(del gt updn[i,0] and del lt updn[i,1],nmb)
  print,numbr_for_arr
;  postnflrarray[i]=numbr_for_arr  ;;  what if there is more than one element?
  if (nmb GT 0) then postnflrarray[i] = numbr_for_arr[0]
endfor
```